# Saving images using Aforge

Tags: c#, aforge

i wrote a code for accessing webcam and on clicking, saving the picture to a folder.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Imaging;
using AForge.Imaging.Filters;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

namespace cam
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static Bitmap _latestFrame;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private FilterInfoCollection webcam;
    private VideoCaptureDevice cam;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webcam = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        foreach (FilterInfo VideoCaptureDevice in webcam)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(VideoCaptureDevice.Name);

        }
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
      }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cam = new VideoCaptureDevice(webcam[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        cam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cam_NewFrame);
        cam.Start();

    }
    void cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    }
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cam.IsRunning)
        {
            cam.Stop();
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap current = (Bitmap)_latestFrame.Clone();
        string ActiveDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(ActiveDir, @"D://picture/");
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(filepath))
        {
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo OutputDir = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath);
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(filepath, @"name.bmp");
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                current.Save(fileName);
            }
        }
        current.Dispose(); 
    }

    }

    }
```

In the button2 I have written the code for saving the picture, on building the program, an null reference exception  is shown for the given line(`Bitmap current = (Bitmap)_latestFrame.Clone();`)

Comment: In the code above, `_latestFrame` never seem to be assigned any value?

Comment: should it be given as null?

Comment: Before you can clone it, `_latestFrame` has to be set to a non-null value. As far as I can see in your code, `_latestFrame` is never set, and thus when you call `_latestFrame.Clone()` a null reference exception will obviously be thrown.

Comment: i am new to csharp. If i am not wrong i have just intialized the webcam. now i need to capture it before saving. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see in your code, the new image frame is copied to your member variable `bitmap`. The static member `_latestFrame` never seem to be assigned.

Therefore, in your `button2_Click` method, change the first line to:

```
Bitmap current = (Bitmap)bitmap.Clone();
```

Now, provided you have received at least one frame from the webcam when you click the button, the frame should be properly saved.

I also think you are overworking the `filepath` setting in the `button2_Click` method. To begin with, simply verify that the picture can be properly saved to the active directory by changing your `button2_Click` method to this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap current = (Bitmap)bitmap.Clone();
    string filepath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(filepath, @"name.bmp");
    current.Save(fileName);
    current.Dispose();
}
```

This will ensure that a new image will be written to the "current directory" every time you click on the *Capture* button.

I have tested your code with the above changes, and it works flawlessly.

Comment: i made the change bt nothing is saved in the picture folder :-(

Comment: Hi Sir thanks for the support..I made the change, but  the current directory can be anything, can we specify it to a specific folder.Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, I just suggested `CurrentDirectory` as a first test. You can specify any folder as long as the path name is valid and you have write access to that location.

Comment: Sir, if you dont mind can i ask one question more. As you said everytime when i click its overwriting the previous image. is der any way not to over write it instead to save as another image

Comment: For that, I would recommend that you implement e.g. a [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx). With this you can ask the user to give a [FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx) and save your bitmap with this file name.

Comment: Sir, your support was awsome..as i a beginner, i am not use to these syntax...am trying to implement what you said. Thanks:-)

Comment: Sir,I used the incrementation procedure and is working as i needed:-) Huge Thanks for the support.